# List out data-attr in <li> using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've various `div` having `data-attr`. I want to list out all `data-attr` value in `li` using jQuery. Please help me. Below is my `html` and my expectation is noted below its.

```
<div data-attr="one">Contents goes here</div>
<div data-attr="two">--</div>
<div data-attr="three">----</div>
```

My Expectation

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div data-attr="one">Contents goes here</div>
<div data-attr="two">--</div>
<div data-attr="three">----</div>
<ul></ul>

$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("div[data-attr]").each(function () {
   $('ul').append('<li>'+$(this).data('attr')+'</li>');
  });
});
```

you can use JQ append

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through all `div[data-attr]` using `each()` and append `data-attr` of each `div` in `ul`.

```js
$("div[data-attr]").each(function () {
    $('ul').append('<li>'+$(this).data('attr')+'</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-attr="one">----</div>
<div data-attr="two">----</div>
<div data-attr="three">----</div>

<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this,

```js
$('div').each(function(){
 var data = $(this).data('attr');
  $('ul').append('<li>'+data+'</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-attr="one">Contents goes here</div>
<div data-attr="two">--</div>
<div data-attr="three">----</div>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over elements which have `data-attr` and generate `li` using it's attribute value as text

```js
// generate ul element
$('<ul>', {
  // set html content by iterating over content div
  html: $('[data-attr]').map(function() {
      // generating `li` with div content as text
      return $('<li>', {
         text: $(this).data('attr')
      })
    // getting array of li
    }).get()
// appending beginning of the body
}).prependTo('body')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-attr="one">Contents goes here</div>
<div data-attr="two">--</div>
<div data-attr="three">----</div>
```

**FYI** : If you want to remove the div then use `$('[data-attr]').remove()`

Comment: @NaveenSadasivanS : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

you need to loop through every `div` using jquery's  `.each()` and create a `li` item with the `data-attr` value and append it to newly created unordered list.

**JS CODE:**

```
 var list = $('<ul></ul>');
 $('.parent div').each(function() {
   $('<li></li>').text($(this).data('attr')).appendTo(list);
 });
 $('.parent').append(list);
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/4jcvs8ga/2/)

Comment: thankyou @dreamweiver. One thing I don't like to write <ul> on my html. I need to list the items automatically. Any way thankyou for your advice. I'm a beginner in javascript

Comment: well thats not difficult @NaveenSadasivanS , you just need to create a unordered list `ul` dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do,

1. Select div elements with `data-attr` attribute using JQuery filters.

   `var elements=$("div[data-attr]");`
2. Go through each element (Using JQuery each() method) and get the value of `data-attr` attribute (Using JQuery attr() method) and append it to `<ul>` element Using JQuery append() method

Here is the complete JavaScript code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var elements=$("div[data-attr]");  

   elements.each(function () {
         $('ul').append('<li>'+$(this).attr('data-attr')+'</li>');  
   });
});
```